How to implement move to click with interactable objects? Event order is breaking the system
Using Godot 4, I want to make a point and click style game where:

if the player clicks on an object (interactable), highlight the object,
else, move the player to the clicked location.

I have a Camera2D which move the player on click:
extends Camera2D

@export var controlled: Player

...

func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        get_viewport().set_input_as_handled()
        if event.is_pressed():
            var pos = self.get_global_mouse_position()
            controlled.clicked_to(pos)

And an Interactable object in my game:
extends Area2D
class_name InteractableArea

...

func _on_input_event(viewport: Viewport, event: InputEvent, shape_idx: int) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
            viewport.set_input_as_handled()
            if event.pressed:
                EventBus.interactable_clicked.emit(true, self)
            else:
                EventBus.interactable_clicked.emit(false, self)

Problem is: I want to make sure we try the event in the Interactable before trying to move the player.
According to this section of the doc, that will never work:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html#how-does-it-work
Because Godot always tries the "_unhandled_input" (in my camera) before passing to the "Physics Picking Events" (which is the event passed to the Area2D).
How do you make a "move to mouse click", while keeping the option to capture the click first to trigger other events?

Try using intersect_point to first check if the position at which you've clicked on has an Area2D and if it does   you can avoid moving your player and directly interacting as needed
you can set the PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D parameter as such:
var space = get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var parameters = PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D.new()

parameters.position=<mouse-click-position-here>
parameters.collide_with_areas = true
... # set other necessary properties

var result : Dictionary = space.intersect_point(parameters)
for obj in result:
    if(obj is InteractableArea):
        ... # something like obj.interact()



This has been a long-standing issue with Godot and there are proposals to change/amend the behaviour: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/79826
One hackish work-around you could do would be to monitor whether the mouse is over your clickable object, use _unhandled_input to handle the click and stop propagation there:
extends Area2D

var is_mouse_over := false

func _on_mouse_entered(): is_mouse_over = true
func _on_mouse_exited(): is_mouse_over = false

func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
            get_viewport().set_input_as_handled()
            if event.pressed:
                print("clicked")
            else:
                print("released")

However, since clicks propagate in reverse order of the scene tree, this only works as long as your objects are lower in the tree than the player, or whatever else they want to keep the click from.
